# What the difference between ethers.ContractAt and ethers.Contract?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

What the difference between ethers.ContractAt("", address) and ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer)?

Answer (score 5):

`hre.ethers.getContractAt("MyContract", contractAddress);`: Gets a deployed instance of a contract, thats why it requires the address, a**nd belongs to the hardhat environemnt** (`hre`).

`ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer)`: Returns a new instance of the Contract attached to a new address. **This is an ethersjs method**.

There is not a `getContractAt` on ethersjs